# C# TCP First Message Delay

Tags: asynchronous, tcp, connection

greetings,

i am writng a socket program using sockets in c# (asynchronous).

the issue is, when a client connects to the server it kinda happens quiet fast. then..

when the first message is sent there is a delay in responding.

this only happens to the very first data being sent over the connection. and boh client and server suffers from this behaviour.

what is this delay? is there a way to get rid of this?

many thanks.

Comment: Does this occur only over the net or also on localhost using loopback? Do you wait after opening the socket or do you immediately try to use it (remember three-way-handshake)?

Comment: i havent tried it on the net, just using localhost loopback.
no i dont use the connection as soon as it is avaliable.
im a beginner so what is 3-way handshake?

Comment: For three-way handshake, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment. However, I don't think this is related if you're not immediately trying to use the connection.. Hmm.

Comment: yea i dont think it is a handshake issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the issue by doing a handshake between the nodes. its more of a hack than a solution.